# Get links in div on separate lines

Tags: html, css, styling

I have following code:

```
    <div>
        <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
        <a href="www.amazon.com">Amazon</a>
        <a href="www.apple.com">Apple</a>           
    </div>
```

This gives:

```
 Google Amazon Apple
```

How do I get

```
Google
Amazon
Apple
```

Comment: Add css: `div a { display: block; }`

Comment: That is not a good solution since it will make the whole line clickable. The cleanest solution is probably using `a:after`  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbKLvN (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve the issue without making the whole line clickable:

```
div a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Check the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbKLvN

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
a{
    display:block;
}
```

Or use `display:table`

Because anchor tag by default `display: inline`.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srLmfqwk/)

Comment: Using `display: block;` is not a good solution since it will make the whole line clickable. Check my answer for a better solution.

Comment: Have you read my whole answer properly? another solution i also given

Answer (score 1):

- `a {display:block;}`
- or add `</br>` after your a tag

Comment: Using `display: block;`is not a good solution since it will make the whole line clickable. Check my answer for a better solution. Using `<br />` is considered bad practice (using markup solely for display related issues).

Answer (score 1):

try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6eexyje/)**

css:

```
div a:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make link clickable by the whole width of parent element, use `display: block`.

```
a {display: block}
```

If you want to make links clickable just in their real width, use `display: table` and `table-row`.

```
div {background: lightgrey; display: table}
a {display: table-row}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hcukvvz5/

Or `float` in combination with `clear`.

```
a {float: left; clear: left;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hcukvvz5/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
a{
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srLmfqwk/)

Comment: Using display: block; is not a good solution since it will make the whole line clickable. Check my answer for a better solution.

Comment: you are also using `display:block;`

Comment: Yes, but not on the link itself. I'm using it on a pseudo element `:after` which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you go with (display: table;) because (display: block;) covers full width anchor points.